# Creating a reference to a variable inside another property

Tags: javascript, performance

I am passing the variable **evtID** which is inside the **vars** object, into click event inside the **createEvent** method. I have to reference it using **cal.vars.evtID**, I was wondering if there is anyway to pass this as reference another variable to make the amount of typing shorter?

Basically I don't want to have to type cal.vars.variable name for every variable I create in the vars object.

```
var cal = {    

    vars: {
        evtID: 0 // here
    },

    createEvent: function(){

        $('.square').on('click',function(){     
            var array = [
                '<div class="event" id="event' + cal.vars.evtID + '">', // and here
                    '<div class="close"></div>',
                '</div>'
            ];

            $('.event-container').append(array.join(""));
        cal.vars.id++;

        });
    },

    init: function(){
        this.createEvent();
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
    cal.init();
}
```

Comment: That seems to be the minimum already. You can assign `cal.vars` or `cal.vars.evtID` to a local var if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make it shorter.

In your code `this` is re-assigned in the click handler, but otherwise you could use it to access the current object:

```
var cal = {    
    vars: {
        evtID: 0 // here
    },
    createEvent: function(){
        this.vars.evtID;
    }
}
```

If you wanted to use it inside the handler you'd have to store a reference to it:

```
createEvent: function(){
    var that = this;
    $('.square').on('click',function(){     
         that.vars.evtID;
    }  
}
```

Or store a reference directly to `vars`:

```
createEvent: function(){
    var vars = this.vars;
    var evtID = vars.evtID;
    $('.square').on('click',function(){     
         vars.evtID;
         evtID;
    }  
}
```

In the second case the `evtID` variable will contain the value to the number, so if you change it the value of cal.vars.evtID wil not change.

Comment: While using `that` wont make it shorter, a often better solution is - for readability and maintainability - not to pass an anonymous function to the click handler but define it outside and pass it with e.g. `.on('click', $.proxy( this.createElement, this ) )` or use a polyfill for `bind`to support older browsers and use `.on('click',  this.createElement.bind(this) )`.